# Kafka : how consumer can know the message type before casting in receive?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message-queue

I have a consumer (implements `ICommonConsumer`) that should call receive when receiving a message

```java
T receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Class<T> classType, Class<?>... genericTypes);
```

My problem is that, some users send messages of `classType` `CommonMessage.class`, some send their customized message type like `CustomizedMessage extends CommonMessage`. I don't know what I should cast the record into.

There is a field in `CommonMessage` which indicates what the type is, but it's too late if I just cast the record to `CommonMessage` and retrieve the type, because in this case I have to redo a cast into their customized types. I wonder what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This ultimately depends on what serializer you are using.

One possible option is to wrap the true event in a type of envelope/metadata layer, then deserialize twice

Example record (as JSON):

CommonMessage: `{"type": "common", "data": {...}}`

CustomMessage: `{"type": "custom", "data": {...}}`

Then your deserializer would have something like

```
Map<String, Class<IMessageDeserializer>> m = new HashMap();
m.put("common", CommonDeserializer.class);
m.put("custom", CustomDeserializer.class);
```

And reading the messages

```
JsonObject value = record.value();
String type = value.get("type");
Class<IMessageDeserializer> clz = m.get(type);
if (clz != null) {
    // innerDeserialzier = clz.newInstance()
    // data = innerDeserialzier.deserialize(value.get("data"))
}
```

Look into https://cloudevents.io/ for a similiar idea